# Calling a method as a variable

Tags: java, if-statement, awt

I have what I think is a simple question but I cannot find the answer. I simply want to use the value returned by a method in an if else statement. I don't want to call the method in the body of the if statement, I want the method to be used in the comparison. My goal is to be able to control a box on the screen but currently I am just trying to test if my arrow key methods work. Thanks for any help!

```
package robot;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Robot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (keyPressedLeft==true) {
             System.out.println("You pressed the left arrow");
        }
    }
    public boolean keyPressedLeft(KeyEvent e){ 
        if (e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just put the print statement in the `keyPressedLeft()` method instead of `main()`.

Comment: How do you intend to have access to the value returned by the method without ever calling it?

Comment: `"I don't want to call the method in a statement, I want the method to be used in the comparison."` -- Huh? Please clarify as this doesn't make sense. At all.

Comment: Edited for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I don't want to call the method in a statement, I want the method to be used in the comparison." No just by name, you can't get anything. You will have to change your statement from

```
if (keyPressedLeft==true) {
```

To

```
if (keyPressedLeft(parameter)==true) {
```

Which can be further reduced to

```
if (keyPressedLeft(parameter)) {
```

Comment: The reason for this is that `==` is checking to see if they are the same static memory unit. `true` is a primitive data type while `keyPressedLeft()` is a method, so obviously they cannot be the same. You want to actually get the return value of the method and see if that returned value is the same as `true`

Comment: When I do this it says I cannot convert boolean to KeyEvent. I put true in for the parameter.

Comment: @MK4. Parameters of a method have a type. You can only pass parameters of this type. Passing a boolean to a method that takes a KeyEvent as argument doesn't make sense. Just like trying to put a credit card into a soda vending machine taking coins.

Comment: So can I do something like 'if (keyPressedLeft returns (true))' I tried that and it does not work, I am almost positive my coding is not right but is that generally what I need to do?

Comment: `public boolean keyPressedLeft(KeyEvent e)` To call the method you must give it a `KeyEvent` which you would have to create yourself. If you just want something to print when the key is pressed, just put the print statement in the `keyPressedLeft()` method.

Comment: @MK4 at this point, you should buy a book introducing Java and read it from the very beginning. Note that if your goal is to detect key presses in the console, this won't ever work. KeyEvent is an event fired by Swing graphical components. You can't use that in a console program.

Comment: I am taking an online class for school...not the best idea especially because the text book is about worthless. I am only trying to make it display text because I want to make sure the KeyPressed method is working before I begin coding the rest of my program